# How to sign documents with an advanced electronic signature after KYC

Tags: pdf, public-key-encryption, electronic-signature, pades

In order to onboard users, we have to identify them and they need to sign a contract (through our web application). The signed contract must be compliant with eIDAS AdES, so a PAdES.

The users are identified either through [SPID](https://www.spid.gov.it/) or [onfido](https://onfido.com/) (but it could be any other KYC service).

What do we need to do in order to produce a valid PAdES? Can we produce one on our own, without a third party?

For what I understood, we can't create a signed PDF because we don't have the private key of the user. If we create a self-signed certificate, the signature would not be valid and we would be able to prove nothing.

Comment: "For what I understood, we can't create a signed PDF because we don't have the private key of the user." Do you know where the private key is? Is it on the users computer? If so, you could client side PAdES and that way their private key never leaves their computer.

Comment: @Ryan The user doesn't have any private key. I was just writing what my understanding is so far.

Comment: @Ryan Let's say I know nothing about this. We have a web application, users signs up, they are identified through KYC. What would be the steps to have a PAdES signed by users?

Comment: You say "they need to sign a contract" and "The signed contract must be compliant with eIDAS AdES". Thus, they need a private key associated with them. That key does not necessarily have to reside on their computer. It might also be on a smart card, or it might be in some web service.

Comment: @mkl "in some web service" do you have some example?

Comment: What if the keys and the certificate are generated in the browser and the user must download them (for the user to take ownership of the key and the certificate), a reference of the KYC is placed in the document, then the document is signed and sent back to backend. Would this be compliant even if the certificate is self-signed?

Comment: *"in some web service" do you have some example?* - Remote signing services. For example [sign-me](https://www.bundesdruckerei.de/en/solutions/sign-me), one such service in Germany. Similar services should also be available in Italy.

Comment: *"What if the keys and the certificate are generated in the browser and the user must download them"* - it depends. Such signatures clearly are not qualified eIDAS signatures. That clearly does not improve know-your-customer objectives. So maybe that's not ok. You should talk with your legal department first to know for sure what kind of signatures would be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231376/discussion-between-denis-frezzato-and-mkl).

Answer (score 1):

Document signing in KYC compliant process usually requires a qualified signature.
"Qualified signature" in all cases is created on QSCD device listed in the EU QSCD list.
I work for company that has a component that enables signing od PDF or XML files according the PADES and XADES signature standards using user x.509 certificate (stored on card, USB roken or in local certificate store on the OS) that enables web applications to get signed document or just CADES signature with few lines of code. Most important works on most modern browsers on both Windows and MacOS operating systems. If you are interested please check our PDF Signing Extension developer portal https://developers.nextsense.com for more details.

Comment: Our legal department said that AdES is enough for our use case, so QES is not required.

Comment: The QES is AdES created with qualified certificate stored on qualified electronic signature device. If signature value is created using local sored certificate the solution proposed previously is the same. Same goes if you sign using for example Adobe Acrobat sign functionality. If certificate selected during signing is qualified you get PDF signed with QES (also AdES), if you select any other x.509 certificate that is not issued in qualified procedure you receive normal AdES (signature). AdES vs QES refers to certificate verification path not to signature format itself.